# Run a celery task every 90 mins from 1:30am-6am UTC

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-celery, celerybeat

Can we make a celery task run at  1:30, 3:00, 4:30, 6 AM using single crontab function?

i.e `'schedule': crontab(minute=30, hour='1, 3, 4, 6')` will run it at 1:30, 3:30, 4:30, 6:30AM

but I want it to run every 90 mins from 1:30 to 6AM

Answer (score 1):

I would create two separate schedules (*not separate function*) as

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "task_one": {
        "task": "path.to.task.my_task_function",
        "schedule": crontab(minute="30", hour="1, 4")
    },
    "task_two": {
        "task": "path.to.task.my_task_function",
        "schedule": crontab(hour="3, 6")
    },
}
```

Here, the schedules are pointing towards the same function named ***`my_task_function(...)`***, but with separate schedules configs.

In this setting, the `task_one` will execute at 1.30 and 4.30 UTC whereas the `task_two` will get executed at `3.00` and `6.00` UTC